# Python - Extracting distinct/unique frames from Videos

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to extract distinct frames from videos. I used opencv(code below) which lets me extract all the frames from a video but what I'm looking for are unique images which don't overlap each other. Any suggestions? TIA.

```
import cv2
import os

video = cv2.VideoCapture("INPUT.MOV")

currFrame =0

while(True):
   ret,frame = video.read()

   if ret:
       name = './data/frame'+ str(currFrame) + '.jpg'

       cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

       currFrame += 1
   else:
       break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

EDIT:
it's a continuous video. For example, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBLQbOG8Z1Y , in this, I need the separate shots of the skyline i.e, one at the 1st second and one at 6th second.

[1st Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5KiH.png)
[6th Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKaA1.png)

Comment: What is the definition of a "unique" image from one frame to the next?

Comment: if 1st image covers the 1st and 2nd second of the video, then the 2nd image should consist of the 3rd and 4th second of the video. So, the 2nd frame should start from the edge of the first frame. Let me know if this makes sense, else I'll try to elaborate in a different way.

Comment: Can you elaborate on it? Does your video contains different images as a slideshow, or is it one continuous video? Please define "unique".

Comment: I've updated the question with an example. Hope its clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want second-wise, you can divide the code and check for the first frame of every second (Frames per second)

> ```
> video = cv2.VideoCapture("INPUT.MOV")
>   
> try:
>     # creating a folder named data
>     if not os.path.exists('secondWiseData'):
>         os.makedirs('secondWiseData')
>
> except OSError:
>     print ('Error: Creating directory of data')
>
> currentframe = 0
>
> #Check the version of opencv you are using
> # Find OpenCV version
>
> (major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')
>
> # if int(major_ver)  < 3 :
> fps = int(video.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS))
> #Else    
> fps = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
>
> #The FPS generated could be decimal as well. We get its greatest interger function by casting to int().
>
> print('The FPS of the video is ', str(fps))
> time_start=time.time()
>     
> while(True):
>       
>     # reading from frame
>     ret,frame = cam.read()
>   
>     if ret:
>         # if video is still left continue creating images
>         name = './secondWiseData/frame' + str(currentframe) + '.jpg'
>         
>         if currentframe % fps == 1: 
>             print ('Creating...' + name)
>             cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
>             currentframe += 1
>             continue
>         else:
>             currentframe += 1
>             continue
>   
>         # increasing counter so that it will
>         # show how many frames are created
>         
>     else:
>         break
>
> time_end=time.time()
> print('Total time taken is ', time_end-time_start)    
> print('Total frames are ', currentframe)
>
> #Release all space and windows once done
> cam.release()
> cv2.destroyAllWindows()
> ```

This will give you the frames of every second in the video considered.